# linux: how grep work

Tags: linux, grep

I am using grep for some time,but there is some question when I use grep.
when I use 'grep' to search some string on nginx error log,I try two ways:
one:

```
grep 404.* error.log
```

for this,there is nothing find

two:

```
grep '404.*' error.log
```

for this, there can find lines that contain 404 in error.log

in my example, '404.*' is the pattern,based on the result,I think when the pattern with single or double quote,the wildcard in the pattern can work, if no quote, the wildcard just treated as literal string.
is it right?

Comment: yes, you're right about that. Patterns are always supposed to be used within the quotes.

Comment: Why not read [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)?

Comment: @HoboSapiens, sorry, I was too careless

Comment: You can also search without quotes by escaping the '*'. Try `grep 404.\*`

Comment: @AnuragPeshne thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, without the quotes, the shell will treat it as a [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and expand it itself if there are any filenames starting with `404.` in the current directory:

```
~ $ mkdir newdir
~ $ cd newdir
~/newdir $ touch 404.foo 404.bar somethingelse
~/newdir $ ls
404.bar 404.foo somethingelse
~/newdir $ echo 404.*
404.bar 404.foo
```

This is not what you want when you're using grep, so you should always quote the search pattern.

```
~/newdir $ echo '404.*'
404.*
```